# For loop help in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, click

**JS Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('sortByTestName');

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var current = list[i].innerHTML;
        list[i].onclick = function() {
            window.alert(current);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Ok so the code here iterates through html file finding elements by `class name` and i made a `for loop` that goes through that. All the elements are displayed on the screen and when one element is clicked i would like to alert the value of the element that was clicked. For example lets say elements are numbers 1-10. They are displayed vertically in page and when user clicks on say number 3 browser should alert in box 3. Everything in terms of design/display is working. The problem I have is that when ever I click on any element the last element is always showing. In terms of our number example if user clicks on number 5 last number 10 is showing. If user clicks on any number last number is showing. I believe this is because the whole loop is executing before something is clicked. I am wondering how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('sortByTestName');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].onclick = function() {
    window.alert(this.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```css
div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="sortByTestName">
  <span>Here is some inner html</span>
</div>
<div class="sortByTestName">
  <span>Some more inner html</span>
</div>
```